# Setting a StringGrid column header height

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, vcl

There is a my vcl application. In form, there is a StringGrid. I want to set column header height but I dont know that how it do.
So the questions is: how to set StringGrid column header auto row height because column row width is not certain

Comment: There is no *auto row height*, that would word wrap a long cell entry into several lines and increase the height of the row correspondingly. You need to do that yourself in your code.

Answer (score 6):

There is no real column header in a `TStringGrid`, just a number of fixed rows (default `1`).

Just set the height for the row you want with the indexed property `TStringGrid.RowHeights`

```
StringGrid1.RowHeights[0] := 42; // set first row height
```